# Loading saved byte array to memory stream causes out of memory exception

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, memorystream

At some point in my program the user selects a bitmap to use as the background image of a Panel object. When the user does this, the program immediately draws the panel with the background image and everything works fine. When the user clicks "Save", the following code saves the bitmap to a DataTable object.

```
MyDataSet.MyDataTableRow myDataRow = MyDataSet.MyDataTableRow.NewMyDataTableRow(); //has a byte[] column named BackgroundImageByteArray
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    this.Panel.BackgroundImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    myDataRow.BackgroundImageByteArray = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Everything works fine, there is no out of memory exception with this stream, even though it contains all the image bytes. However, when the application launches and loads saved data, the following code throws an Out of Memory Exception:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(myDataRow.BackGroundImageByteArray))
{
    this.Panel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

The streams are the same length. I don't understand how one throws an out of memory exception and the other doesn't. How can I load this bitmap?

P.S. I've also tried

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(myDataRow.BackgroundImageByteArray.Length))
{
    stream.Write(myDataRow.BackgroundImageByteArray, 0, myDataRow.BackgroundImageByteArray.Length); //throw OoM exception here.
}
```

Comment: Often GDI+ (what `Image` is built on) will through Out Of Memory execptions when really what has happened is you got Out Of Handles from not disposing disposable objects.

Comment: How often is your `this.Panel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);` code called?

Comment: At this point it's called only once. I imagine it would never be called more than a handful of times.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think is here:

```
myDataRow.BackgroundImageByteArray = stream.ToArray();
```

Stream.ToArray() .  Be advised, this will convert the stream to an array of bytes with length = stream.Length.  **Stream.Legnth is size of the buffer of the stream**, which is going to be larger than the actual data that is loaded into it.  You can solve this by using `Stream.ReadByte()` in a `while` loop until it returns a -1, indicating the end of the data within the stream.

Comment: Thanks, that's makes sense that the buffer would be larger than the data it contains. I get the loop thing, but I'm having trouble finding how to create a mutable byte array to which I can add bytes one byte at a time in the while loop. Any pointers? (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

You might give this library a look.

http://arraysegments.codeplex.com/

**Project Description**

Lightweight extension methods for ArraySegment, particularly useful for byte arrays.

Supports .NET 4.0 (client and full), .NET 4.5, Metro/WinRT, Silverlight 4 and 5, Windows Phone 7 and 7.5, all portable library profiles, and XBox.